# Value stored to "lastScale" is never read

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a validation method by which I analyse whether a particular variable passes a validation criteria.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)scaleTextView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestRecognizer{

CGFloat scale = pinchGestRecognizer.scale;
CGFloat lastScale;
lastScale = 1.0;
if([pinchGestRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    // Reset last scale
    lastScale = 1.0;
    return;
}
if ([pinchGestRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
    [pinchGestRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGFloat pinchscale = [pinchGestRecognizer scale];
    CGFloat scaleDiff = pinchscale - lastScale;

    if (scaleDiff < 0){
        scaleDiff *= 2; // speed up zoom-out 
        [self zoomSymbol:selectObject Scale:-scale];
    }
    else{
        scaleDiff *= 0.7; // slow down zoom-in 
        [self zoomSymbol:selectObject Scale:scale];
        lastScale = pinchscale;
    }
}    
}
```

I get warnings 'Value stored to' lastScale 'is never read' and 'Value stored to' scaleDiff 'is never read'
Can anybody explain me what is my problem here.
Thank everybody!

Comment: Yap: your problem is that... quote: "Value stored to `lastScale' is never read". Voila!

Comment: I dont get the point in setting lastScale = 1.0; in UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded and also ur assigning values to scaleDiff, but the variable is not used anywhere.

Comment: I'm using here // Reset last scale
    lastScale = 1.0;
    return;

Comment: Ya, whats the point in setting the value? Its local variable. I mean every time the function is called lastscale will be allocated right.

Comment: Yes, Thank all. problem has been solved.
Thank all very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastScale` is a local variable and will never make it to all cases of the gestureRecognizer's state property. You should use a `static` variable instead.

```
static CGFloat lastScale = 1.0;
...
```

Comment: Should he not use an instance variable instead?

Comment: It depends on what he wants to achieve really. Anyway, since you only have one viewController's view on screen at a given time and set the value of lastScale also when the gesture begins, it doesn't really matter. But yes, he could also put the variable in an ivar.

Comment: FYI, ivars are preferred over static variables.